# Unable to run sample Facebook App

Tags: android, facebook

I have been working on this all day. I have followed multiple tutorials including the one on facebooks developers site and the one on mybringback.com. I am just trying to get the sample application working. 
So far it works on the emulator. it allows me to sign in. Granted i have not installed the facebook apk on the emulator. On my phone i just get 'An error has occured.' message. The stack trace only gives an error message when the app crashes upon exiting. Error is `Unable to resume activity... caused by Failure delivering result ResultInfo....` its a null pointer exception when the application tried to resume from attempting facebook login.

- I have my facebook app id in the hackbook sample application from facebook sdk.
- I have generated a keyhash with the command that the facebook sdk instructs you to use.
- I have also used this tool from easyfacebookandroidsdk to somehow get a second keyhash. I did not know which one would be the correct one so i put both of them in the dashboard.
- I have updated the facebook application on my testing device.
- I entered the package name and class name.

com.facebook.android
com.facebook.android.HackBook

Is there anything else that i need to do with the sample application besides replace the app_id?

Is there anything else that might affect my application from logging into facebook?

Just trying to get a new direction on this because i feel like i have exhausted my brain resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So..... I feel a little stupid but i cannot believe that i did not stumble on this info in my searches.

My application was not working because i had facebook already installed on my phone and i was logged in as a different user than i develop with. Once i logged out in the actual facebook application everything worked flawlessly.

Not an error in settings. Thanks for all your help Viewers there was actually not much to go on since everything was actually setup correctly.